# Remove specific word in variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

In a `bash` script, how can I remove a word from a string, the word would be stored in a variable.

```
FOO="CATS DOGS FISH MICE"
WORDTOREMOVE="MICE"
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${FOO//"$WORDTOREMOVE"/}"
CATS DOGS FISH
```

This also work in `ksh93` (where it comes from), `mksh` and `zsh`.

---

POSIXLy:

```
FOO="CATS DOGS FISH MICE"
WORDTOREMOVE="MICE"

remove_word() (
  set -f
  IFS=' '

  s=$1
  w=$2

  set -- $1
  for arg do
    shift
    [ "$arg" = "$w" ] && continue
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
  done

  printf '%s\n' "$*"
)

remove_word "$FOO" "$WORDTOREMOVE"
```

It assumes your words are space delimited and has side effect that remove spaces before and after `"$WORDTOREMOVE"`.

Answer (score 63):

Using `bash` substring replacement (copied from ksh93):

```
FOO=${FOO//"$WORDTOREMOVE"/}
```

The `//` replaces all occurrences of the substring (`$WORDTOREMOVE`) with the content between `/` and `}`.  In this case nothing.

Note the quotes around `$WORDTOREMOVE` to make sure the contents is taken as a fixed string instead of a pattern.

When the replacement is empty, the `/` can also be omitted: `${FOO//"$WORDTOREMOVE"}`.

For information on this and other ways to work with strings in bash, see the section [10.1. Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) of the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: wouldn't this break if the $WORDTOREMOVE contained regex significant characters?

Comment: It seems that if the WORDTOREMOVE contains slash themselves, we need to escape the slash. For example `FOO=refs/heads/bugfix`, and we want to remove `refs/heads/`, we need to use `${FOO/"refs\/heads\/"/}` to get `bugfix` only.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) like this:

```bash
echo $FOO | sed s/"$WORDTOREMOVE"//
```

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions here suppress a substring, not a complete word, and will fail in strings like "CATS DOGS FISH MICE CIMICES". In bash, we can use the `=~` operator to match word boundaries, as below :

```
$ foo="CATS DOGS FISH MICE CIMICES"
$ word="MICE"
$ regex="^(.*)\b$word\b(.*)$"
$ [[ "$foo" =~ $regex ]]
$ printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
CATS DOGS FISH  CIMICES
```

However, this construction will remove the word only once. To remove all occurrences of the word with this method, you will need to loop around the pattern matching, for example:

```
$ foo="MICE CATS DOGS FISH MICE CIMICES MICE"
$ word=MICE
$ regex="^(.*)\b$word\b(.*)$"
$ while [[ $foo =~ $regex ]]; do foo="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; done
$ printf "%s\n" "$foo"
 CATS DOGS FISH  CIMICES
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing one *word* from a string representing a whitespace-delimited list of words is not that easy, because you need to decide what to do with the spacing on each side.

Even in a tamed representation where there's always a single space between the words, you need to differentiate several different cases:

- word in the middle: `foo MICE bar` -> `foo bar`: word and the spaces before and the spaces after replaced with a single space. `${var/+( )MICE+( )/ }`
- word at the start: `MICE foo bar` -> `foo bar`: word and the spaces after replaced with nothing: `${var/MICE+( )}`
- word at the end: `foo bar MICE` -> `foo bar`: word and the spaces before replaced with nothing: `${var/+( )MICE}`.
- then there's the problem of several successive occurrences of the word where `${var// MICE / }` wouldn't work on `foo MICE MICE bar` because the first replacement would eat up the space that precedes the second MICE.

(above using the `${var/pattern/replacement}` operator from ksh93).

It becomes easier though if you add a space at the start and at the end before doing the substitution and remove them afterwards, as then you can cover all grounds with one substitution operator:

```
var='MICE foo MICE MICE bar MICE'
word=MICE

var=" $var "
var=${var//+(+([[:space:]])"$word")+([[:space:]])/ }
var=${var# } var=${var% }
```

You'd need `shopt -s extglob` in bash or `set -o kshglob` in zsh beforehand to support that `+([[:space:]])` ksh88 operator to match 1 or more whitespace characters.

Or using `zsh`'s own `extendedglob`s (`set -o extendedglob`) where ksh's `+(x)` becomes `x##`:

```
var=${var//([[:space:]]##$word)##[[:space:]]##/ }
```

It's even possible to restore the spacing that was after or before the words with (in `zsh`; ksh93 would have something equivalent, not bash):

```
var='MICE foo MICE MICE bar MICE'
word=MICE

set -o extendedglob
var=" $var "
var=${var//(#b)([[:space:]]##$word)##([[:space:]]##)/$match[2]}
var=${var# } var=${var% }
```

If instead of a scalar variable containing a representation of a list, you have an actual *list* (array) variable, as in:

```
var=(MICE foo MICE MICE bar MICE)
```

Then the problem is reduced to removing specific elements from the array which becomes trivial with shells with proper array variables such as `zsh` (where that `var=(foo bar)` syntax comes from):

```
var=( ${var:#$word} )
```

Answer (score 0):

An implied requirement here is to match whole words. To facilitate that, I am including "WERECATS" into the `FOO` example.

```
FOO="CATS DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS"
```

### Using gnu `sed`

gnu sed supports word boundary matching `/b`, which works also for the first word (no leading whitespace) and last word (no trailing whitespace). This fixes a problem where substring matching could occur in compound words:

```
$ echo "$FOO" | sed "s/\bCATS\b//g"
 DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS
```

^ notice the leading space here. Sed matching word boundaries this won't remove the spaces, just the word. If you also want to normalize the string to a regular space-delimited list, pipe `xargs` like so:

```
$ echo "$FOO" | sed "s/\bCATS\b//g" | xargs
DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS
```

Same thing, but avoiding `echo`. Note that the placement of `<<<` can be ahead of or behind the command `sed` depending on your preference.

```
$ sed "s/\bCATS\b//g" <<< "$FOO" | xargs
DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS
$ <<< "$FOO" sed "s/\bCATS\b//g" | xargs
DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS
```

### POSIX compliant matching

This is a little trickier, as there does not seem to be an easy way to match word boundaries in the posix standard. As a workaround, we can convert the string to newline delimited (`\n`) and then use grep with the start-of-line `^` and end-of-line `$` anchors to match whole lines, and again using `xargs` to neatly reassemble the list into a regular space-delimited result:

```
echo "$FOO" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v "^CATS$" | xargs
DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS
```

One can also use `printf` instead of `tr` to convert the input string into lines. Note how in this special case `$FOO` is *not* quoted:

```
printf "%s\n" $FOO | grep -v "^CATS$" | xargs
DOGS FISH MICE WERECATS
```

Comment: See `grep -vxF CATS` to remove lines made entirely  of `CATS`.

Comment: Note that leaving `$FOO` unquoted in shells such as bash performs split+glob on the expansion. While you do want the split part (for which you'd want to set `$IFS` to specify the separators), you do not want the glob part which you'd need to disable. Test with `FOO='* CATS /*/*/'` for instance.

Comment: Beware `\b` matches on boundaries between word characters (alnums or underscore) and non-word characters (any other character), not between whitespace and non-whitespace. It would still remove `CATS` inside `WILD-CATS`.